# How to solve that the Open Xchange `/opt/open-xchange/sbin/registerserver` command gives `Look-up failed. Service "OXUtil_V2" is not available.` error

Tags: open-xchange

I'm new to Open Xchange and trying to install it on a clean Debian 10.7 VM by following the [official installation instructions](https://oxpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=AppSuite:Open-Xchange_Installation_Guide_for_Debian_10.0).

I installed MariaDB on the same server, gave the root user a password (`root_db_pass` #example), created a new database (`open_xchange`) and a user (`open_xchange_user`) with password (`ox_db_pass` #example).

Followed all steps from the installation instructions which works fine until i need to register the local server at he Open-Xchange configdb database (`/opt/open-xchange/sbin/registerserver -n oxserver -A oxadminmaster -P admin_master_password`), then i receive the error

```
root@axx-oxch-srv01:~# /opt/open-xchange/sbin/registerserver -n oxserver -A oxadminmaster -P admin_master_password

server could not be registered:
Server response:
 Look-up failed. Service "OXUtil_V2" is not available.
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:227)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(RegistryImpl_Skel.java:133)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:469)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:301)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:279)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:380)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:123)
        at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
        at com.openexchange.admin.console.util.server.RegisterServer.<init>(RegisterServer.java:77)
        at com.openexchange.admin.console.util.server.RegisterServer.main(RegisterServer.java:91)
```

I Googled this issue but there is almost nothing to find about this. I checked the passwords 3 times to be sure i did not make a typo! How can i fix this ?

---

**Some extra info which may be required to help me out**

used `initconfigdb` command

```
/opt/open-xchange/sbin/initconfigdb --configdb-dbname open_xchange --configdb-user open_xchange_user --configdb-pass ox_db_pass --mysql-root-passwd root_db_pass
```

used `oxinstaller` command

```
/opt/open-xchange/sbin/oxinstaller --no-license --servername=oxserver --configdb-pass=ox_db_pass --master-pass=admin_master_password --network-listener-host=localhost --servermemory 1024
```

If more data is needed, let me know an i will update my question...

---

**UPDATE 1**

I just found that there is also logged something which differs from the message i get in the console. The log entries bellow pop up after i the `service open-xchange restart` which is required after executing `/opt/open-xchange/sbin/oxinstaller --no-license --servername=oxserver`

Logs:

```
2021-01-07T01:56:55,546-0600 INFO  [pool-8-thread-1] com.openexchange.startup.impl.osgi.DBMigrationMonitorTracker$1.run(DBMigrationMonitorTracker$1.java:132)


        Open-Xchange Server v7.10.4-Rev14 initialized. The server should be up and running...

2021-01-07T01:57:01,425-0600 INFO  [OXTimer-0000006] com.openexchange.push.impl.balancing.reschedulerpolicy.PermanentListenerRescheduler.cancelTimerTask(PermanentListenerRescheduler.java:207)
Canceled timer task for rescheduling checks
2021-01-07T01:57:01,439-0600 WARN  [OXTimer-0000006] com.openexchange.database.internal.ReplicationMonitor.checkActualAndFallback(ReplicationMonitor.java:181)
DBP-0001 Categories=SERVICE_DOWN Message='Cannot get connection to config DB.' exceptionID=808265395-5
com.openexchange.exception.OXException: DBP-0001 Categories=SERVICE_DOWN Message='Cannot get connection to config DB.' exceptionID=808265395-5
        at com.openexchange.database.DBPoolingExceptionCodes.create(DBPoolingExceptionCodes.java:260)
        at com.openexchange.database.internal.ReplicationMonitor.createException(ReplicationMonitor.java:245)
        at com.openexchange.database.internal.ReplicationMonitor.checkActualAndFallback(ReplicationMonitor.java:174)
        at com.openexchange.database.internal.ReplicationMonitor.checkActualAndFallback(ReplicationMonitor.java:157)
        at com.openexchange.database.internal.ConfigDatabaseServiceImpl.get(ConfigDatabaseServiceImpl.java:138)
        at com.openexchange.database.internal.ConfigDatabaseServiceImpl.get(ConfigDatabaseServiceImpl.java:133)
        at com.openexchange.database.internal.ConfigDatabaseServiceImpl.getReadOnly(ConfigDatabaseServiceImpl.java:173)
        at com.openexchange.database.internal.DatabaseServiceImpl.getReadOnly(DatabaseServiceImpl.java:152)
        at com.openexchange.push.impl.PushDbUtils.getContextsWithPushRegistrations(PushDbUtils.java:296)
        at com.openexchange.push.impl.PushDbUtils.getPushRegistrations(PushDbUtils.java:256)
        at com.openexchange.push.impl.PushManagerRegistry.getUsersWithPermanentListeners(PushManagerRegistry.java:834)
        at com.openexchange.push.impl.balancing.reschedulerpolicy.PermanentListenerRescheduler.reschedule(PermanentListenerRescheduler.java:364)
        at com.openexchange.push.impl.balancing.reschedulerpolicy.PermanentListenerRescheduler.doReschedule(PermanentListenerRescheduler.java:341)
        at com.openexchange.push.impl.balancing.reschedulerpolicy.PermanentListenerRescheduler.checkReschedule(PermanentListenerRescheduler.java:327)
        at com.openexchange.push.impl.balancing.reschedulerpolicy.PermanentListenerRescheduler$1.run(PermanentListenerRescheduler.java:284)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at com.openexchange.threadpool.internal.CustomThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(CustomThreadPoolExecutor.java:1016)
        at com.openexchange.threadpool.internal.CustomThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(CustomThreadPoolExecutor.java:1041)
        at com.openexchange.threadpool.internal.CustomThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(CustomThreadPoolExecutor.java:834)
        at com.openexchange.threadpool.internal.CustomThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(CustomThreadPoolExecutor.java:861)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.openexchange.pooling.PoolingException: Cannot create pooled object.
        at com.openexchange.pooling.ReentrantLockPool.get(ReentrantLockPool.java:320)
        at com.openexchange.database.internal.AbstractMetricAwarePool.get(AbstractMetricAwarePool.java:149)
        at com.openexchange.database.internal.AbstractMetricAwarePool.get(AbstractMetricAwarePool.java:72)
        at com.openexchange.database.internal.TimeoutFetchAndSchema.get(TimeoutFetchAndSchema.java:93)
        at com.openexchange.database.internal.ReplicationMonitor.checkActualAndFallback(ReplicationMonitor.java:167)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
===>>> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'openexchange'@'localhost' (using password: YES) <<<===
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
...
...
```

Note this line: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'openexchange'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. This is interesting as `openexchange@localhost` is not the user i give during the `initconfigdb` command and also not corresponds with the database user i created in MariaDB.

I tried to create such user with the same password as the user i created and executed everything again but unfortunately this results in the same error. I have no idea where Open Xchange gets this user from...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the default username is used in the error, described in update 1. This because the parameter `--configdb-username=open_xchange_user` is missing in the `oxinstaller` command.

This also made me thing that the `--configdb-database=open_xchange` is probably required as well.

I also added the parameter `--configdb-writehost=localhost` to the oxinstaller command as this seems to be required as well if you only use 1 database server instead of a cluster. (see https://oxpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=OXLoadBalancingClustering_Database#Configure_OX_to_use_with_a_standalone_database)

So my updated `oxinstaller` command looks like this:

```
/opt/open-xchange/sbin/oxinstaller --no-license --servername=oxserver --configdb-server=open_xchange --configdb-user=open_xchange_user --configdb-pass=ox_db_pass --configdb-writehost=localhost --master-pass=admin_master_password --network-listener-host=localhost --servermemory 1024
```

After this everything works fine.